# For ever "Pending …" when accessing repository in SVN Repository Explorer

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, eclipse-indigo, svn-repository

When opening our repository in Eclipse's SVN Repository Explorer "Pending …" is displayed forever.

Interestingly I can access the repository without problems with my browser.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: Could it be a firewall issue? That Eclipse is trying to reach the repository on a port that isn't open?

Comment: I don't think so. It's been actually working for some time.

Comment: Get a stack trace of your eclipse (kill -3 on Unix, or run Eclipse from a console window on windows and do a control-break, or use pstack) and that will tell you something about the problem.